# The onclick function is not working in safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

kindly help me on this because this code works in chrome the onclick function is ok but when i run this in safari in won't go in the #Download id and it won't reload the page.

here is my code:

```
<a href="#Download" onclick='window.location.reload(true);'> <div class="download"> 

<p class="download_text">Downloaded</p> 

</a>
```

Comment: Is it supposed to do both, scroll to the element, **and** reload the page?

Comment: maybe but the only thing i need here is to go the #Download.

Comment: why not create event handler?

Comment: Then just remove the `onclick` handler?

Comment: this code is ok in chrome but in safari is not.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this function:

```
function reload() { 
 if (window.location.href != "Download.html#") {
   window.location.href="Download.html#"
 } 
}
reload()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the onclick event with onfocus solved the problem. I guess Safari doesn't like onclick event on select elements.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#Download" onfocus='window.location.reload(true);'> <div class="download"> 
        Downloaded
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```